# Inheriting styles from default CSS style while overriding one property

Tags: css

Let's say I have the following CSS defined:

```
.scrabble-container {
clear: both; }
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .scrabble-container {
    margin-left: 15px; } }

.scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__space {
    width: 90px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #D5B292;
    color: #2A1F1B;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px 3px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    cursor: default;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.8), inset 3px 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), inset 0 3px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset -2px -3px 0px rgba(143, 128, 82, 0.6); }

.scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter {
    background: #D5B292 no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #c8c8c8, 3px 0 2px rgba(213, 178, 146, 0.4) inset, 0 3px 0 rgba(213, 178, 146, 0.5) inset, -3px -4px 0 rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.6) inset;
    color: #2A1F1B;
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Spinnaker", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin: 10px 3px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 35px; }
    @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter {
        width: 31px;
        height: 31px;
        line-height: 25px;
        font-size: 18px; } }
    @media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
    .scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter {
        width: 40px;
        height: 47px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 47px; } }
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter {
        width: 53px;
        height: 58px;
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 58px; } }
```

I would like to create a new CSS class called `.scrabble-tile__letter__R` that inherits all the properties from the `.scrabble-tile__letter` class except the background is red. I can do the following:

```
   .scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter__R {
        background: #e9afaf no-repeat scroll 0 0;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #c8c8c8, 3px 0 2px rgba(213, 178, 146, 0.4) inset, 0 3px 0 rgba(213, 178, 146, 0.5) inset, -3px -4px 0 rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.6) inset;
        color: #2A1F1B;
        cursor: default;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        font-family: "Spinnaker", Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: 400;
        height: 35px;
        line-height: 32px;
        margin: 10px 3px;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        width: 35px; }
        @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
            .scrabble-tile__letter__R {
            width: 31px;
            height: 31px;
            line-height: 25px;
            font-size: 18px; } }
        @media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
        .scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter__R {
            width: 40px;
            height: 47px;
            display: inline-block;
            float: none;
            font-size: 24px;
            line-height: 47px; } }
        @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        .scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter__R {
            width: 53px;
            height: 58px;
            font-size: 30px;
            line-height: 58px; } }
```

But this become unwieldy if I have multiple different colors I'd like to apply via CSS. What is the correct way to do this such that I can inherit all the properties (including the `@media screen` components), while overriding just the background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the common styles to both classes:

```
.scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter,
.scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter__R {
  background: #D5B292 no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #c8c8c8, 3px 0 2px rgba(213, 178, 146, 0.4) inset, 0 3px 0 rgba(213, 178, 146, 0.5) inset, -3px -4px 0 rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.6) inset;
  color: #2A1F1B;
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: "Spinnaker", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin: 10px 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 35px; 
}

/*Here the color change*/
.scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter__R {
  background-color: #e9afaf;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter,
  .scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter__R {
    width: 31px;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 18px; 
  } 
}
    
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter,
  .scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter__R {
    width: 40px;
    height: 47px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 47px; 
  } 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter,
  .scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter__R {
    width: 53px;
    height: 58px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 58px; 
  } 
}
```

Element:

```
<div class='scrabble-tile__letter__R'></div>
```

---

Or create some additional classes just for the colors:

```
.scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter {
  background: #D5B292 no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #c8c8c8, 3px 0 2px rgba(213, 178, 146, 0.4) inset, 0 3px 0 rgba(213, 178, 146, 0.5) inset, -3px -4px 0 rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.6) inset;
  color: #2A1F1B;
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: "Spinnaker", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin: 10px 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 35px; 
}

etc..

.scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter.red {
  background-color: #e9afaf;
}

.scrabble-container .scrabble-tile__letter.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Element:

```
<div class='scrabble-tile__letter red'></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I didn't understand how inheritance worked before seeing this example